# Unpermitted parameter in devise registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to create a user's account from the devise registration page. How do I go about creating an account from a user registration page?

I have the following models:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  belongs_to :account
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
end


class Account < ApplicationRecord
  validates :alias, presence:true
  has_many :users, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
end

class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]

  def new
    super do |r|
      r.build_account
    end
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    super
  end

  protected

  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [
      :first_name,
      :last_name,
      :country_code,
      :phone_number,
      account_attributes: [
        :alias
      ]
    ])
  end
end


Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }
end
```

I have the following views:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

  ...

  <%= f.fields_for resource.account do |account_form| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= account_form.label :alias %><br />
      <%= account_form.text_field :alias %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I try to sign up, I expect the code to create an account, and link it to an existing user.

What I get instead is the following error:
Unpermitted parameter: :account

The account does not get created and the error printed to the user is that the account can't be empty.

Comment: Hello, welcome.  Please post your models related to this form with nested

Comment: It seems like you are treating `user` as the parent and `account` as the child, but it's the other way around. The account needs to be created before the user. Calling `super` will not work because devise [creates the resource before yielding to the block](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L20). It may be best to copy/paste the devise code and modify it...perhaps making the association optional will work.

Comment: I got my answer from the docs at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html "Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent." Since user is a child of account, using accepts_nested_attributes_for is unsupported in this case and wont work the way I intended the form to work. Looks like I'm going to have to go with @MarkMerritt suggestion and completely replace the devise controller logic with my own.